# How to use lsd_slam with usb camera?

Tags: ros, lsd-slam, camera, usb-cam, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install lsd_slam from  [here](https://github.com/tum-vision/lsd_slam). I run succesfully lsd_slam with .bag files from taken [here](http://vision.in.tum.de/lsdslam). I want to try lsd_Slam with usb camera or image sequence. To do it, I run below commands :

```
roscore
rosrun lsd_slam_viewer viewer
rosrun lsd_slam_core live_slam  /image:=/usb_cam/image_raw _calib:=pinhole_example_calib.cfg
roslaunch slam.launch
```

slam.launch

```
<launch>
<!-- Activate the color webcam. -->
<node name="usb_cam" pkg="usb_cam" type="usb_cam_node" output="screen" >
    <param name="video_device" value="/dev/video0" />
    <param name="image_width" value="640" />
    <param name="image_height" value="480" />
    <param name="pixel_format" value="yuyv" />
    <param name="camera_frame_id" value="usb_cam" />
    <param name="io_method" value="mmap" />
</node>
<!-- Convert the color webcam's output to mono. -->
<node name="to_mono_node1" pkg="image_proc" type="image_proc" ns="usb_cam" />
<!-- Display the mono stream. -->
<node name="image_view" pkg="image_view" type="image_view" respawn="false" output="screen">
    <remap from="image" to="/usb_cam/image_mono" />
    <param name="autosize" value="true" />
</node>
</launch>
```

Error is :

```
Input resolution: 752 480
In: 0.527334 0.827306 0.473568 0.499436 0.000000
NO RECTIFICATION
Output resolution: 752 480
Prepped Warp matrices
Started  constraint search thread!
Started mapping thread!
Started optimization thread 
UndistorterPTAM: input image size differs from expected input size! Not undistorting.
Doing Random initialization!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I use ros-indigo, ubuntu 14.04. How can I run lsd_slam with images or usb camera frames?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212883/how-to-use-lsd_slam-with-usb-camera?/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is complaining about your input image size.

Modify your "pinhole_example_calib.cfg", and don't forget to change the camera parameters in the first line. You can get those parameters by calibrating your camera with [ptam's tool](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/Tutorials/camera_calibration).

```
0.527334 0.827306 0.473568 0.499436 0
640 480 
crop
640 480
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-04**:
ptam's tool uses catkin, but lsd_slam uses rosbuild. If I use `rosbuild_ws/package_dir$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x5 --square 0.030 image:=/usb_cam/image_raw --no-service-check` , isn't it  sufficient calibration task?

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-04**:
Yeah, it should be sufficient. But the question is how to link these parameters.
http://answers.ros.org/question/212251/whats-the-relationship-between-camera-calibration-values-in-ethzasl_ptam-camera_calibration/

**Comment by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on 2015-07-06**:
Thanks your help. But this link has a only question. It hasn't an answer.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2015-07-06**:
Yes, because I am also trying to figure out how to interpret these parameters...maybe by tracing the code: https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam/blob/master/ptam/src/CameraCalibrator.cc
But for now I don't have much time on this project.